# path to local file using ssh command to upload directory to remote server?

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm trying to upload a folder from my local machine to a remote server using putty command.

I'm trying to copy a folder and subfolder using this syntax

```
scp -r [file/folder to be copied] some_user@my_ip:[destination_folder]
```

I can login ok and run the command but get an error to the local path ?

I have tried different paths to the local folder ie. `c:/folder/folder` - /folder/folder etc but i get an error saying no such file or directory exists - so I'm asking what is the correct path to include if the folder you want to copy is on your local machine - `c:/documents/upload/folder`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The folder you are trying to copy into does not exist on your server and scp will not create it for you. You can copy a local folder recursively into an existing folder on your target machine as

```
scp -r localfolder name@host:destination
```

and you will now have destination/localfolder at the remote system.

If you want to copy the files into destination, but not the localfolder itself you can use

```
scp -r localfolder/* name@host:destination
```

and your files (and subdirectories) from local folder will now be in your destination on the remote system.

But I don't know of any way for scp to create the destination folder should it not exist.

Comment: What is the correct path on my local machine if the folder is in c:/documents/folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy folders directly with scp. You have to tar/zip/bzip them first.
Anyway if you have one level of files in source directory you can use dir_path/* to copy files inside to destination.

Comment: The scp I have used (on GNU/Linux, Solaris, OSX have all supported the -r argument). pscp on window is also documented to copy recursively with -r.